# AppDelegate not triggered at start?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have a tab bar controller defined as initial controller, with 3 underlying controllers A (default), B and C.

My addDelegate/didFinishLaunchingWithOptions initialize BD info if it is the first launch.

When I run the app for the first time, it crashes in B view controller because of un-initialized data (B is not the default one).
This data should have been initialized in the addDelegate, but it is not !

Here is my appDelegate.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        print("Start")
        alreadyLaunch = defaults.bool(forKey: "alreadyLaunch")

        if !alreadyLaunch  {
            print("First launch")
            try! realm.write {
               settings.localCurrency  = Currencies.sharedInstance.getCurrency(withKey: "EUR")
               }
        } else {
            print("Already launched")
        }

        // Rest of code...

        Return true
    }
```

It seems that it crashes right at the start because the print("Start") is not triggered. I also put a breakpoint on it.

It's like if the view controller was initialized right at start before the end of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, before settings.localCurrency is initialized.

- Can a tab bar controller be the initial view controller ?
- Is it normal that the second view controller of the tab bar controller is initialized before I tap on the second button ?

Thanks

Comment: The code you have posted is near useless in helping to diagnose this issue. Please show how 'BD values' are initialized and passed to the tab controller. I suspect that BD values are initialized async and the results are not returned before your tab controller is initialized

Comment: I edited the question with initialization.

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get the *real* place where the crash occurs. And where do you set `alreadyLaunch` to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

A sa trick, I put a view controller as initial view controller in front of the tab bar controller. His function is to automatically segue to the tab bar controller, so there is no change for the end user.

By doing that, the appDelegate code is executed normally and all is correct.

Seems that it's not a good idea to have the tab bar controller as initial view controller. Weird, but anyway it's OK now...